# Display the data I get from ajax on view

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

This is the modal where I want to display the value I get from ajax data but it's not working. I have the `id="view_name"` on span element. I don't know what the problem is it won't display

This is the code that triggers the `fun_view` function:

```
<td>
    <a href="" data-id="" class="display" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="fun_view('{{ $dat->id }},{{ $dat->name }},{{ $dat->company_name }}, {{ $dat->mobile_phone }}, {{ $dat->timezone }}, {{ $dat->best_time_to_call }}')"><?php echo $dat->name;?></a>
</td>

<div class="modal-body">         
    <p><b>Name : </b><span id="view_name" class="text-success"></span></p>
    <p><b>Company Name : </b><span id="view_company_name" class="text-success"></span></p>
    <p><b>Mobile Phone : </b><span id="view_mobile" class="text-success"></span></p>
</div>

<script>        
function fun_view(id,name,company_name,mobile_phone,timezone,best_time_to_call)
{
    var view_url = $("#hidden_view").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: view_url,
        type:"GET", 
        data:
        {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "company_name": company_name,
            "mobile_phone": mobile_phone,
            "timezone": timezone,
            "best_time_to_call": best_time_to_call
        },
        success: function(result){
          //when I alert(result.name) it says undefined
          $("#view_name").text(result.name);
          $("#view_company_name").text(result.company_name);
          $("#view_mobile").text(result.mobile_phone);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: result.name is json object type ! So check your ajax response is json

Comment: What says ```console.log(result)``` ?

Comment: show what you return from the url also add `dataType:'json',` in ajax

Comment: What's the data u r passing and I don't c any trigger to execute the function!

Comment: @developerbh this is code that triggers the function <a href="" data-id="" class="display" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="fun_view('{{ $dat->id }},{{ $dat->name }},{{ $dat->company_name }}, {{ $dat->mobile_phone }}, {{ $dat->timezone }}, {{ $dat->best_time_to_call }}')"><?php echo $dat->name;?></a>

Comment: @guradio on console when i check the param tab i get the id name company_name mobile timezone and that's the one i pass on fun_view function

Answer (score 0):

Add **datatype** just to make sure that the ajax response is in JSON object
 and i'm wondering about the selector $('#hidden_view') maybe you have some CSS that hides it.

$.ajax({

```
    url: view_url,
    type:"GET",
    datatype: 'JSON',
    data: {"id":id, "name":name, "company_name":company_name, "mobile_phone":mobile_phone, "timezone":timezone, "best_time_to_call":best_time_to_call },
    success: function(result){
      //when i alert(result.name) it says undefined
      $("#view_name").text(result.name);
      $("#view_company_name").text(result.company_name);
      $("#view_mobile").text(result.mobile_phone);
    }
```

});

try the above code

Answer (score -1):

You might have forgotten to include a reference to the JQuery script.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```